# cron time stamp variable assignement not working - Solaris

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cron, solaris

Several questions and answers have been written about CRON already, but I can't find one that addresses this scenario; The sample script below runs successfully if called via command line:

```
LogDir=/usr/local/gtpsft/scripts/tmp
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`

LogMsg ()
{
   #set -xv
   CODE=$1
   MSG=$2

   echo "$(date +"%H:%M:%S") : ${CODE} : ${MSG}" >> ${LogDir}/${DATE}_XXXX_GCF_Restart.log

}

#fn=TimeTests.sh
current=`perl -le 'print int(time)'`
file_time=$(ls -E TimeTests.sh | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 }'| sed -e 's/-/ /g' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/\..*$//')
epoch_file=`gawk -v t="${file_time}" 'BEGIN { print mktime(t)}'`


LogMsg INFO "Current EPOCH time:        ${current}";
LogMsg INFO "File time stamp in FULL:   ${file_time}";
LogMsg INFO "File time stamp in EPOCH:  ${epoch_file}";
```

But the line:

```
file_time=$(ls -E TimeTests.sh | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 }'| sed -e 's/-/ /g' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/\..*$//')
```

fails to execute (no value is stored in variable) if this is run from cron, I have tried to add the full PATH to the script, and even calling the profile within the script, i.e.:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gcc:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/perl5/lib:/opt/hpnpl/lib:/usr/share/lib:/usr/local/samba/lib
PATH=/usr:/usr/bin:/sbin:/opt/sfw/bin:/usr/sbin:/etc/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/sfw/cups/bin:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/share/lib:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/local/samba/bin:/usr/local/sbin

/bin/bash /etc/profile
```

But the results remain the same when the script is run from cron, I have tried using other commands to get the EPOCH file time stamp i.e.:

```
stat -c %Y TimeTests.sh
```

But the results remain the same when run from CRON... Any suggestions to what I am missing would be greately appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `/bin/bash /etc/profile` is effectively a  no-op. The settings in the profile script take effect **only** for the `/bin/bash` instance that you just ran and not for the script running that command. You need `. /etc/profile` or `source /etc/profile` for that.

Comment: What directory do you think you are operating in when the cron job is running? Where do you think the script is looking for `TimeTests.sh`? Using the full path there should fix that problem (and using `stat` is **infinitely** better than [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

Comment: If you add `set -x` to the script do you see it running the commands you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I had tried . and source but the results are the same

Comment: Yes, it works as expected only when called from cron the line --- file_time=$(ls -E TimeTests.sh | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 }'| sed -e 's/-/ /g' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/\..*$//')  ---- doesn't seem to execute

Comment: Yes, I didn't expect the profile thing to matter I was just explaining why that wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: You have no shebang on the code included here. Which shell are you using?

Comment: @Faizers, pay closer attention to Etan's comment: "What directory ..."

Comment: thanks glenn and Etan... the issue was with the path for the file name... guess I have been looking to the screen for too long today... Much appreciated

Comment: @miken32 the shebang line was #!/bin/bash -x  the issue is now sorted, the path to the file was not included in the script...

Answer (score 0):

The issue with line

```
file_time=$(ls -E TimeTests.sh | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 }'| sed -e 's/-/ /g' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/\..*$//')
```

was that the path to TimeTests.sh was not included therefore when the script was triggered by cron TimeTests.sh could not be found, this was fixed by adding the full path i.e.:

```
file_time=$(ls -E /usr/local/gtpsft/scripts/tmp/TimeTests.sh | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 }'| sed -e 's/-/ /g' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/\..*$//')
```